# Mac Poppler + pdf2image PATH bug

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, poppler

**Problem:**
I've been attempting to use the Python library pdf2image, which I am aware requires the prior installation of poppler. Poppler is installed (via homebrew) and the package via pip.

However, when running `convert_to_path(my_pdf)` I get the following:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-9-ba107659b495>", line 1, in <module>
    test_image = convert_from_path(testfile,

  File "/Users/<myuser>/.pyenv/versions/3.8.0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pdf2image/pdf2image.py", line 97, in convert_from_path
    page_count = pdfinfo_from_path(pdf_path, userpw, poppler_path=poppler_path)["Pages"]

  File "/Users/<myuser>/.pyenv/versions/3.8.0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pdf2image/pdf2image.py", line 467, in pdfinfo_from_path
    raise PDFInfoNotInstalledError(

PDFInfoNotInstalledError: Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?
```

**My System**:
Mac, OC 10.15.7
Python (via Homebrew) version 3.8.0

```
which python
/Users/<myuser>/.pyenv/shims/python
which pip
/Users/<myuser>/.pyenv/shims/pip
```

What I've tried so far:
Poppler is installed via homebrew (`brew install poppler`) and pdf2image installed with `pip3 install pdf2image`
I've run `brew cleanup` too.

Attempted to force the poppler path in convert_to_path with the following,

```
pop_path = "/usr/local/Cellar/poppler/21.03.0_1"
convert_to_path(my_pdf_file,poppler_path = pop_path)
```

but still get the same error.

Had a decent look online and found many people with similar, yet not identical, problems. I feel like I must be doing something wrong, so any guidance would be great.

Answer (score 1):

**Partial Solution?**

In manually entering the pop_path file path, I forgot to append /bin to the path,

```
pop_path = "/usr/local/Cellar/poppler/21.03.0_1/bin"
```

The code works now. Though my pride will take some time to recover...

I feel like I might still be sitting on a bad configuration issue? The many posts on similar issues seem to imply a homebrew installed-popper shouldn't have this issue. Is it maybe because I am using pyenv too?

Answer (score 0):

if you use conda environment run the below code in mac terminal

```
conda install -c conda-forge pdf2image
conda install -c conda-forge poppler
```

It solve the problem